# A Chronometer problem in an android application

Tags: android, android-studio

First I create a Chronometer instance.

```
Chronometer chronometer;
```

Then I create Start, Stop, On Tick events.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    chronometer = new Chronometer(this);

    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            TimerStart();
        }
    });

    btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            TimerStop();
        }
    });

    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometerChanged)
        {
            chronometer = chronometerChanged;
            count++;
            txt_count.setText(String.valueOf(count));

            if (count >= seconds)
            {
                count = 0; 
                //play sound
            }
            
        }
    });
}
```

Ans Start, Stop methods

```
void TimerStart()
{
    seconds = Long.parseLong(txt_seconds.getText().toString());
    count = 0;

    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());  
    chronometer.start();

    is_running = true;
}

void TimerStop()
{
    chronometer.stop();
    is_running = false;
}
```

Then I start the chronometer and set a break point on **count++;** line in onChronometerTick event.
But I get there only once and it stops.

What do I miss?

Comment: Try to remove `chronometer = chronometerChanged;`.

Comment: I tried. No effect.